# expect script: set the output of ls command to a variable

Tags: shell, unix, expect

I'm new to shell scripting and navigating different script languages.

I'm writing an expect script where I want to set the output of a ssh ls command to a variable to loop through, like the following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
var=$(ssh user@host ls path | grep 'keyword')

echo $var

for x in $var;
# do stuff 
done
```

But I'm not sure how to do this in an expect script. Other examples I searched seem to be setting the output of `send` to a variable--is this the route?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Capturing the output of a sent command into an expect variable is actually a PITA. The captured output contains the command and the prompt: suppose your prompt is `"> "` and you send the `date` command. Expect will see this:

```
"date\r\nTue Nov 15 11:34:16 EST 2016\r\n> "
```

So you need to do this to capture the output:

```
send -- "date\r"
expect -re {^[^\n]+\n(.*)\r\n> $}
set output $expect_out(1,string)
```

In that complicated pattern:

- `^[^\n]+\n` will match the command you send (up to the first newline) -- this is `date\r\n`
- `(.*)\r\n` is the output of the command (up to the last line ending)

  - expect will store the captured text in the variable `expect_out(1,string)`
- `> $` is where you match your prompt.

So your program will be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
spawn ssh user@host
expect -re {\$ $}      ;# regular expression to match your prompt

send -- "ls path | grep keyword\r"
expect -re {^[^\n]+\n(.*)\r\n$ $}
set output $expect_out(1,string)

send -- "exit\r"
expect eof

puts $output
```

Comment: it says:  can't read "expect_out(1,string)": no such variable

Comment: Does your prompt end with a dollar sign and a space? If not, you have to adjust that regular expression.